# How to add value to user default array with swift 4

Tags: arrays, swift, permanent

I'm trying to append and save a series of strings using UserDefaults, but my code is replacing the data instead of adding to the array every time its called, what am I missing?

```
if Plus == true
    {

        if typeOfMath != [""]
        {

        typeOfMath.append("Addition")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(typeOfMath, forKey: "typeMath")
        print ("\(typeOfMath)")
        typeOfMath = [""]

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you try to set the value in UserDefaults each time, it actually overwrites the value for the key.

What you need to do is :

1. Read the existing array in UserDefaults
2. Append new value to this array
3. Write this array back to UserDefaults.

Comment: Got it! thank you! I added                                                                               if  var  mathData = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "typeMath")
                {
                    mathData.append("\(typeOfMath)")
                    typeOfMath = mathData
    
                }                                                                                                    my data looks like this: ["Addition", "[\"Addition\"]", "[\"Addition\"]"], how do i get rid of the brackets so it will look like ["Addition", "Addition", "Addition"] ?

Comment: @Daniel.wu I think you can use this `mathData.append(contentsOf: typeOfMath)`